# How to loop multiple SELECT separately

Tags: php

I have two queries for which i want to get result in separate while loop, query is working fine but i cant figure out how to get result separated in while loop.

**php**

```
$query = "
SELECT 1 as query, title FROM $tablename WHERE category='category1' LIMIT 10
UNION
SELECT 2 as query, title FROM $tablename WHERE category='category2' LIMIT 10
";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result[1])){
    echo $row['title'].'<br />';
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result[2])){
    echo $row['title'].'<br />';
}
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "
SELECT 1 as query, title FROM $tablename WHERE category='category1 LIMIT 10'
UNION
SELECT 2 as query, title FROM $tablename WHERE category='category2 LIMIT 10'
";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);

$qResult1 = array();
$qResult2 = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if($row['query'] == 1) $qResult1[] = $row;
    else $qResult2[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: how do i fetch result in this seperately.

Comment: It is seperate. $qResult1 holds results where query = 1, $qResult2 where query = 2. What you do with the results then is up to you.

Comment: try it without the strict comparison : `$row['query'] == 1` instead of `$row['query'] === 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "
  SELECT 1 as query, title FROM $tablename WHERE category='category1' LIMIT 10
  UNION
  SELECT 2 as query, title FROM $tablename WHERE category='category2' LIMIT 10
";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['title'].'<br />';
}
```

That's it. Every iteration of the while loop retrieves the next result.

Comment: I tried like this `while($row = mysql_data_seek($result, 0))` it gives error a `mysql_data_seek() expects parameter 1 to be resource`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here? so i can refine the answer.

Comment: as you mentioned in second part i tried and get only one result and an error `mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,`

Comment: I want to get result separated to use in while loop.

Comment: you only need one while loop. give me a second i'll edit my answer into usable code.

Comment: this does not separate result this gives all result.

Comment: how did you want them separated exactly? Do you realize that inside the while loop  it does the same thing for each result?

Comment: result separated, like the result i can get using two separate queries with two separate while loop

Comment: `SELECT title FROM $tablename`

Answer (score 0):

Why not separate two queries?

```
$query1 = "SELECT title FROM $tablename WHERE category='category1' LIMIT 10";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query1) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    echo $row['title'].'<br />';
}

$query2 = "SELECT title FROM $tablename WHERE category='category2' LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query2) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    echo $row['title'].'<br />';
}
```

OR you can loop the categories.

```
$catgories = array('category1', 'category2');

foreach($categories as $cat){
    $query = "SELECT title FROM $tablename WHERE category = {$cat} LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);
    echo $cat.'<br />'
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $row['title'].'<br />';
    }
```

Comment: I have to do this like 10 times so 10 queries.

Comment: @TallboY, no need to repeat, you can use loop. See my updated answer.